# Angular2 Communication Between Components

Tags: angular, components, angular2-injection, angular2-inputs

I search about communication between components with Angular2 i try in this mode but doesn t work

the template variantpages.component.html content this

```
<button (click)="changetext()">Change</button> 
<child></child>



@Component({
  selector: 'menu-left',
  templateUrl: './app/pages/variantpages.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent{


child = new ChildComponent();


 changetext(){ this.child.changetext2()}

}
```

```
@Component({
   selector: 'child',
   template: `<p>page of {{ pageCount }}</p>`
})

export class ChildComponent{

@Input() photo:string = "ciao ciao";

@Output() valueChange = new EventEmitter();


pageCount:number;
constructor(){ this.pageCount = 0; }

changetext2(){
        this.pageCount++;
        this.valueChange.emit(this.pageCount);
        console.log(this.pageCount);
  }
}
```

so the console log show the increment number but pageCount stay a 0

Thanks

Comment: what does your html contains update it to post

Comment: Without looking too closely (meaning there could be other problems as well), but noticed the following... Check *"parent listens for child event"* and the correct use of output in this link: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-view-child Make notice of the childtag in that example. Hint: `<child></child>` is not enough ;) And use `@ViewChild` instead of `child = new ChildComponent();` The link I provided addresses both issues ;)

Comment: hi thanks for answer i put the part of html, the problem is the component call the method changetext2 and i see the increment in the console but dont change in the page

Comment: First of all you should use ViewChild (check the link I gave you). If the problem still persists, please provide a plunker.

Answer (score 0):

ok i solved with EventEmitter but this work only from parent and children, now my question it s different, if i have two different component and i want with one button (click) in component A to change the string in a Component B, i call this method setName

COMPONENT A

```
constructor(private appComponent: AppComponent ){ }
setName(newName: string) {
        this.appComponent.name = newName;
        console.log(this.name);
      }
```

COMPONENT B

```
@Input() name: string = "Angular3"
```

the console show the new string, but the name don't change

Comment: You can use a shared service class for this type of communication. See: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html for more information